# perl sort round robin

Tags: perl, round-robin

I have a hash of a hash that's set up like this:

```
$hash->{$val}->{$val2}
```

Inside of the second hash (the one that corresponds to `$val2`) is a list of values. I could have three lists like this:

```
$hash->{$val}->{1} = [1,2,3]
$hash->{$val}->{2} = [4,5,6]
$hash->{$val}->{3} = [7,8,9]
```

I would like to have the values of these list put into a new array, sorted in round robin order by `$val2`. Thus the result would look like this:

```
@new_arr = (1,4,7,2,5,8,3,6,9)
```

Does anyone know of a way in perl that I could accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: I assume those hash values are really array references?

Comment: yes, they are. sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have CPAN access, you could install [`List::MoreUtils`](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/List-MoreUtils-0.33/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm) and use it:

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(zip);

my @new_arr = zip(@$hash->{$val}{1}, @$hash->{$val}{2}, @$hash->{$val}{3});
```

If the number of key/value pairs in `$hash->{$val}` is dynamic, unfortunately `zip` requires actual arrays due to prototyping (and array refs won't do). Luckily, you can get around it by forcing old-style invocation and passing in the array refs:

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(zip);

my @ordered_array_refs;
push @ordered_array_refs, $hash->{$val}{$_} for sort keys %{$hash->{$val}};
my @new_arr = &zip(@ordered_array_refs);     # nasty :-(
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how I could use zip if there were a variable number of arrays in `$hash->{$val}->{$val2}`? Because how many arrays I will have will be dynamic.

Comment: @srchulo: I've edited my answer. Not 100% sure about it (can't test it here), but give it a shot?

Comment: it doesn't seem to work. I changed the first line to this: `push @ordered_array_refs , $hash->{$val}{$_} for sort keys %{$hash->{$val}};`, because that line didn't work. But even after that zip doesn't allow you to use map like that and gives `Type of arg 1 to List::MoreUtils::mesh must be array (not map iterator)` as an error.

Comment: @srchulo: That might just be operator precedence (i.e., the comma is interpreted as the end of the argument rather than applying to `map`). Try the block form (see edit). You're right about the `push` thing-- that was lazy on my part and I should have researched that better. It's been a while since I've actually written Perl.

Comment: I still get the same error. I also get this one: `Not enough arguments for List::MoreUtils::mesh `. Hmmm...maybe you can't do it.

Comment: Okay... I'll need to test this at home, then. Suggest looking at the `List::Gen` answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/11419633/129655).

Comment: @srchulo: Forgot I had a working interpreter here. I've made another edit; apparently invoking the `zip` subroutine old-style will do it, but it's nasty as hell. I tested it and it seemed to work.

Answer (score 2):

[`List::Gen`](https://metacpan.org/module/List%3a%3aGen)'s `tuples` function can do this as well:

```
my @tuple = tuples [1..3], [4..6], [7..9];

say "@$_" for @tuple;  # 1 4 7
                       # 2 5 8
                       # 3 6 9
```

Comment: Yeah, but I want it to all be in one array. But I guess I could just push the arrays into another one. Thanks! Do you know how to do this for a dynamic number of arrays? Say if there was a dynamic number stored in `$hash->{$val}->{$val2}`?

Comment: @srchulo : There is a `zip` function as well: `my @array = zip [1..3], [4..6], [7..9];`